# Убрать спецсимволы с переменной

Tags: php

Приветствую! Возникла проблема. Вот код с переменной:

```
$put = 'D:\test123\text\txt\1.txt';
file($put);`
```

Проблема в том что файл читает \ (я так думаю но не уверен)как спецсимвол, как это исправить?

Comment: Во первых рекомендую скопировать сюда  текст ошибки или поподробнее описать что конкретно не получается.
и было бы совсем хорошо получить больше кода по двум строчкам особо не поймешь в чем дело

Comment: Ваша проблема не особо понятна, использование функции у Вас верное и переменная правильная, опишите проблему подробнее.

Comment: Проблема в том что если $put = 'D:\test123\text\txt\1.txt';
То происходит ошибка в file($put);
Но если пусть будет $put = 'D:/test123/text/txt/1.txt';
То все нормально. Как мне сделать что бы 1й путь работал?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.addslashes.php

Comment: Так как посторонние люди (не спецы в пхп) к вашему проэкту не имеют, то ставьте \\ вместо \ и всё.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло addslashes.  Всем очень благодарен.